# How to run functions and daemons in Flutter and dynamically change state in StatefulWidget?

Tags: android, flutter, async-await, reactive-programming, future

I am developing a Flutter app for accademic purposes in university. I also started approaching to Flutter's widget paradigm (Stateless vs Stateful). Anyway, considering for a while the Stateful methodology, I need to launch background processes (i.e REST API GET and SQLite update) and then update the state with the new data (e.g in a ListView).

Let me explain better with the following image:

[image]

I tried to outline what I think it should be the information flow.
However, I remember that in Kotlin (native) if I want to do some kind of Async work I need to do something like this:

```
class someTask() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        // ...
    }
}
```

But in Flutter the toolbox we can use is made of other primitives, like **await**, **future** and so on.
My question is: what are the best practices in order to achieve what I want (also in terms of performance and programming patterns) ?

Thank you for your attention